# CPU consumption increased on db2 batch

Tags: db2, batch-processing, compiler-optimization, cobol, jcl

I'm trying to optimize CPU consomption.
I have a DB2 batch that invoke physical accessor that contains database query.
When i run this batch: i have a CPU consumption of 30%.

I want now to eleminate the access to physical accessor and write all query on my batch.
My batch run correctly but CPU consumption has increased to 50%. I'm surprized.

Is there a compile way to compile my batch with ?
Why writing query directly on batch have increased the CPU consumption ?

Comment: CPU percentage is relative and does not give actual consumption. It's more meaningful to compare the total CPU time of the jobs. Besides that, more information would be required about what exactly you have done.

Comment: @not2savvy Even CPU time of the job have increased by 6 sec. I don't understand why !

Comment: Cobol and JCL hints at Db2z. Add more details on your environment, including Db2 version, and the type of work.

Comment: A really efficient algorithm will run at 100% cpu,  just not for very long.